# Trying to simplify this expression using trig identities.

Tags: trigonometry

> Simplify $$\frac{1- \tan^2 x}{\tan x+1}.$$

The answer is $1 - \tan x$ but I can't seem to figure it out. I tried all the identities.

(Edited the bottom from tan(x)-1 to tan(x)+1)

Comment: $1-a^2 = (1-a)(1+a)$ P.S: Are you sure that's the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1-\tan^2x}{\tan x-1} = \frac{(1-\tan x)(1+\tan x)}{-(1-\tan x)}$$

$$ = -1-\tan x$$

Please check the answer carefully-there must be a mistake somewhere.

Edit: If the denominator is $\tan x +1$, then the expression simplifies into $1-\tan x$

$$\frac{1-\tan^2x}{\tan x+1} = \frac{(1-\tan x)(1+\tan x)}{1+\tan x}= 1 -\tan x$$

Comment: Oops, the bottom is supposed to be tan(x) + 1. Thanks.

Comment: @JoshuaMorris, I've edited my answer to include the aforementioned.